# Lightswitch AddAndEditNew_Execute()

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I need to open the dialog which appears after I click the Plus sign in data grid view.
Which means, When i press my button, i need it to appear as if i clicked + button. But now i need to open the grid view and then click on the + button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your screen collection is called "Invoices", in your method code you would simply call

**VB:**

```
Me.Invoices.AddAndEditNew
```

**C#:**

```
this.Invoices.AddAndEditNew();
```

Comment: Hi, This works perfectly. But is there a way I can edit the fields appear. I dont want the client to enter all the fields at runtime. Eg. created date,edited date,computed fields etc.

Comment: Using the default LightSwitch-generated modal windows, the ONLY thing you can influence is which properties appear, or don't appear. In the table designer, with your table open, untick "Display by Default" for any properties that you don't want to appear in the default modal window. For any other types of changes you'd have to create your own custom modal window.